# Sun lights think there is a 200m shade around the camera, the rest of the scene lights don't work at all with shadows turned on. EEVEE Blender 4.0

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting, shadows

first post. Been learning blender in my spare time for about a year, so please keep in mind this could be a very simple problem to you that I just don't know how to fix.

Two crazy things keep happening on a project I am working on, modeling a Star Trek ship, both happen at the same time. This is one of only 2 big projects I've worked on since picking up blender.

First off, spot lights, point lights and area lights just stop working after a few minutes. The spot lights act like there is something in front of them casting a shadow. I say this because if I bump a spot light to 100000002004 GW then a ring around the edge of the cone appears, like there is just another cone directly in front of spot light and a microscopic amount of light is getting through. They work however when shadows are turned off for those lights.

(Point lights and area lights don't work at all as far as I know, no outlines or anything, unless shadows are unchecked on those lights)

Mind you, to take these screen shots I deleted everything in the entire scene to underscore there is nothing in the scene besides an untextured cube and a spot light. First is shadows on, second is shadows off (I guess I also increased the angle in this screenshot, or hadn't decreased it yet)

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Okay so the other thing that happens is that any sun OTHER than the sun in the scene named Sun (no .001) acts like there is an umbrella with a 200m radius around the view. I say view because it is centralized around the view, and only appears on that view. Again, the other suns work if shadows are turned off for that particular sun. First screen is shadows turned on for sun.001, second is shadows turned off.

[image]
[image]

If I restart the program, the lights come back for a bit. If I only reload the project, or even if I start a brand new project, the problem persists.

My computer cannot handle recording live render at a framerate above 2 or 3 frames per second, but the last time I closed the program, restarted, and loaded up the file, I watched the lights dim as if the area was filling with a fog. Don't know if that helps anything click for whoever is reading this.